# Why isn't `height: 100%` and absolute positioning working in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a child div of a flexbox layout fill its parent. In any other context setting the width/height to 100% causes a div to fill its parent... I only wish to use flexbox for my top level layout.

Problems

- `#map-container` div will not fill `#col1` even though it has height 100% set.
- `#controls` div appears outside `#col1` completely. I've previously used absolute layout to align boxes to corners without problems. Being inside a flexbox grand-parent seems to cause issues.

What I'm expecting is `#map-container` and `#map` to fill `#col1` and `#controls` to align to bottom right-hand corner of `#map`.

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#col1 {
   display: flex;
}
#map-container {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;

  height: 100%;    
}
#map {
    background-color: purple;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#controls {
    background-color: orange;    
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#row1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#row2 {
    flex:2;
    display: flex;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1 1;
}
#col2 {
    background-color: blue; 
    flex :0 0 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Header</div>
    <div id="row2">
        <div id="col1">
            <div id="map-container">
                <div id="map">
                    Map
                </div>
                <div id="controls">Controls</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="col2">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. `#map-container` div will not fill `#col1` even though it has height `100%` set.

It won't work that way, because for a percentage unit to work, it needs to have height set on its parent all the way up. This fights against the `flex` model, where the flex-items are distributed and arranged by the flex-box layout and have no dimensions set. **Why use a flex layout when all your elements are `100%`?** Either do a `100%` on all your element all the way up, or do a flex on all containers.

If you stick to flex layout, then you will have to get into nested `flex`. Otherwise, you will get `#map-container` to fill-up, but not the `#map`.

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/sztcb0me illustrates that problem.

> 2. `#controls` div appears outside `#col1` completely. I've previously used absolute layout to align boxes to corners without problems. Being
>      inside a flex-box grand-parent seems to cause issues.

The only issue is that you are positioning it absolutely, but in relation to what? You need to position your `#map-container` relatively for that to work.

Here is how:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/sztcb0me/1/**

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body, .wrapper { height:100%; width: 100%; }
.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#row1 { flex: 0 1 auto; background-color: red; }
#row2 { flex: 2 0 auto; display: flex; }
#col1 { flex: 1 0 auto; display: flex; background-color: green; }
#col2 { flex: 0 0 240px; background-color: blue; }
#map-container { 
    flex: 1 0 auto; display: flex;
    position: relative; background-color: yellow; 
}
#map { flex: 1 0 auto; background-color: purple; }
#controls {
    background-color: orange;    
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px; bottom: 3px;
    width: 100px; height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Header</div>
    <div id="row2">
        <div id="col1">
            <div id="map-container">
                <div id="map">
                    Map
                </div>
                <div id="controls">Controls</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="col2">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clear explanation. The reason I was mixing and matching layouts was because #map is actually a third-party widget (Cesium JS library), this brings along height:100% on various nested levels. I was trying to get the two concepts to play nicely, I didn't mention this in the question as things were complicated enough!

Comment: Thanks @Adam. If you wish you could also very easily use a percent-based fluid layout without flex in this case. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/eqv0jm42/1/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that it's wrapped in   `#map-container`

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#col1 {
   display: flex;
}
#map-container {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;

  height: 100%;    
}
#map {
    background-color: purple;    
    width: 100%;
   /* height: 100%; */
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
#controls {
    background-color: orange;    
    position: relative;
    /*right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#row1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#row2 {
    flex:2;
    display: flex;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1 1;
}
#col2 {
    background-color: blue; 
    flex :0 0 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Header</div>
    <div id="row2">
        <div id="col1">
            <!-- <div id="map-container"> -->
                <div id="map">
                    Map
                  <div id="controls">Controls</div> <!--  add it here -->
                </div>
            <!--    <div id="controls">Controls</div> -->
            <!--</div> -->
        </div>
        <div id="col2">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

adding an absolute position `controls` in that way is not optimal (in the snippet I commented it out) ;  you can place the `controls`nested in `#map` (and use flex properties for correcting placement)